# LINQ (L2E) with stored procedure and IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities

Consider a normal Linq expression will be something like this:
(This is just a sample to make things more understandable)

```
 IQueryable<Person> personQuery= (from ppl in PersonContext  
                      select ppl).ASQueryable();


List<Person>personList = personQuery.where(x => x.age==13).ToList();
```

So if I decided to put the 1st part of the linq query inside a stored procedure,
things will work out something like this.

```
 IQueryable<Person> personQuery= PersonContext.sp_RetrievePerson().ASQueryable();

 List<Person> personList = personQuery.where(x => x.age==13).ToList();
```

So for the question, I believe that the 1st method only sends the sql call when toList() is called.
In another words, the query sent to sql for execution will be

```
Select * from Person where age=13
```

But for method 2, how many times will this query be sent for execution?
If it is only sent 1 time, does it make it redundant to call the stored procedure as stored procedure is known for having a faster execution and how will the query sent to sql look like?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about this one, but `PersonContext.sp_RetrievePerson()` returns an `ObjectResult`, which internally uses a DbDataReader. That means that the stored procedure is called once, the 
`personQuery.where(x => x.age==13)` iterates over the resulting rows and filters out not matching objects.

By using stored procedures for this you might get a small performance gain on querying the database, but you have to evaluate each object in the persons table, AFTER reading it from the database. So I think in this scenario using stored procedures only makes sense, if you provide a parameter `age` to the stored procedure for filtering the results already in the database.

Comment: This is what I'm guessing too. Of cause it is more complex than this sample query. I'm not very good at SQL when it comes to outer join and unions and things like that. But I can manipulate it better using coding with LINQ, and of cause maintain it easier. The table I'm using contain at least 5 unions, in which eat union segment has alot of outer joins. To sum up, that person who wrote that query is too godly but I had to maintain it.